# What is the difference between the anti-image covariance and the anti-image correlation?

Tags: correlation, covariance, factor-analysis, matrix, partial-correlation

What is the difference between the *anti-image covariance* and the *anti-image correlation*? How are the matrices of these coefficients computed, and what is the meaning of their elements?

Comment: What do you mean by "anti-image" here?

Comment: I claim not to close the question: it is clear and "anti-image" is a well-defined term, although it was not explained in the question.

Answer (score 4):

A excerpt of [another answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43224/3277) (about factor analysis), structured.

Let $\bf R$ be a correlation or covariance matrix, and $\bf D$ be the diagonal matrix comprised of the inverses of diagonal elements of $\bf R^{-1}$. Then

- $\bf DR^{-1}D$ is known as *anti-image covariance matrix* of $\bf R$.
  Its off-diagonal entries are the negatives of the **partial covariance
  coefficients** (between two variables controlled for all the other
  variables). The diagonal is equal to the diagonal $\bf D$, - these
  diagonal values are called *anti-images* in $\bf R$.
- $\bf (DR^{-1}D)-2D+R$ is called *image covariance matrix* of $\bf R$.
  Its diagonal entries are called *images* in $\bf R$ (they are equal
  to the diagonal of $\bf R-D)$. An *image* is $R_i^2 \sigma_i^2$,
  where $R_i^2$ is the squared **multiple correlation coefficient** of
  dependency of variable $i$ on the rest variables, and $\sigma_i^2$ is
  the diagonal element in $\bf R$, the variance (or $1$, in case of
  correlation matrix).
- From the above it becomes clear that image + anti-image = $\sigma_i^2$, and that the two are the portions of a variable's variation being, respectively, explained and unexpained (residual) by the other variables. Thus, if $\bf R$ is correlations then image is the $R_i^2$ and anti-image is $1-R_i^2$; while if $\bf R$ is covariances then image is $R_i^2 \sigma_i^2$ and anti-image is $\sigma_i^2-R_i^2\sigma_i^2=\sigma_i^2(1-R_i^2)$.
- Terminologic warning: the image and anti-image covariance matrices
  bear label "covariance" irrespective of whether $\bf R$ is
  covariances or correlations.
- *Anti-image correlation* matrix of $\bf R$ is computed from anti-image covariances the very usual way like we convert usual covariance
  into usual correlation, $r_{ij}=cov_{ij}/(\sigma_i \sigma_j)$, - i.e. here the cov and the two sigmas will be the values from an anti-image covariance matrix. Or in matrix notation: $\bf D^{-1/2} A D^{-1/2}$, where $\bf A$ is the anti-image covariance matrix and $\bf D^{-1/2}$ is its diagonal, square-rooted and inversed. Equivalent formula also is $\bf D^{1/2} R^{-1} D^{1/2}$, where $\bf D^{1/2}$ is the $\bf R^{-1}$'s diagonal, square-rooted and inversed. Off-diagonal
  elements of anti-image correlation matrix are the negatives of the **partial correlation
  coefficients** (between two variables controlled for all the other
  variables). And that is popular way to compute partial correlations.
- One can also convert, analogously, image covariance matrix into image
  correlation matrix, if needed.
- Anti-image correlation matrix will be the same - be $\bf R$
  covariances or correlations (while anti-image covariance matrix was
  different in the two instances).

Comment: great answer!! Any chance you could add a line about the correlation coefficient, and how it relates to these various measures? Thanks!!

Comment: What is the reason (if any) that image and anti-image covariance matrices both bear the label "covariance"?