# Negative Eigenvalues in EFA

Tags: factor-analysis, sas, eigenvalues

Assuming a set of data meet all assumptions for EFA and we are doing a factor analysis (with the SMC used to define the shared variance), how do negative eigenvalues appear and what does that say about the input data? I have spent a bit of time refreshing myself on [how to calculate an eigenvalue](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/MtrxVibe/EigMat/MatrixEigen.html) by hand but I am missing a fundamental connection between eigenvalues and variance in EFA.

Below is an example of negative eigenvalues that appear in a [SAS EFA tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/output/factor-analysis/) on the UCLA webpage.
[image: EFA with negative eigenvalues]

The page goes on to state:

> Some of the eigenvalues are *negative* because the matrix is not of full
> rank.  This means that there are probably only four dimensions
> (corresponding to the four factors whose eigenvalues are greater than
> zero).  Although it is strange to have a *negative* variance, this
> happens because the factor analysis is only analyzing the common
> variance, which is less than the total variance.  If we were doing a
> principal components analysis, we would have had 1’s on the diagonal,
> which means that all of the variance is being analyzed (which is
> another way of saying that we are assuming that we have no measurement
> error), and we would not have *negative* eigenvalues.  In general, it is
> not uncommon to have *negative* eigenvalues.

The above seems to suggest this scenario is not uncommon in EFA and it is due to the matrix not being full rank (googling hasn't helped me understand this in the context of EFA). It also suggests this is in part due to a difference in the common variance (EFA only models common variance) vs total variance (not fully sure where this is in the model).

And a follow-up question:

- Do the proportion and cumulative variance make sense in the above example SAS output or can they be corrected somehow (set all negative eigenvalues to 0 and recalculate the proportion with a new denominator)?

Comment: The statement "the matrix is not of full rank" appears wrong and misleading.  The basic issue is that when you subtract estimates of measurement variance from a covariance matrix, the result is not necessarily a *definite* matrix: that is, it can have smallish eigenvalues (up to the magnitude of the measurement error, roughly). The mere fact that *all* the listed eigenvalues are clearly different from zero *proves* the matrix being analyzed indeed is of full rank.  (Rank deficiency is indicated by eigenvalues equal to zero, up to floating point roundoff error.)

Comment: @whuber - part of your explanation is flying over my head. Does this mean the negative eigenvalues correspond to variance associated with measurement error? Is this shared error variance?

Comment: Principal axis FA puts estimates of communalities instead of 1s on the diagonal of correlation matrix (or instead of variances on the diagonal of covariance matrix). Since communalities are less than those (they represent only part of variance), they are  [causes 2 or 3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/69206/3277) of non-positive-definiteness. They are too small, generally and most of the time, for the matrix to be p.s.d.

Comment: Example of FA of iris dataset, demonstrating negative eigenvalues, is [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102999/3277). Read [also](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/50758/3277).

Comment: When FA iterates at the extraction of factors, [it trains](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/43224/3277) the _m_ factors to maximally explain off-diagonal correlations/covariances, and the corresponding _m_ factors are collectively maximized, and are positive. At the same time, the rest of _p_-_m_ eigenvalues, the dross, are often negative (no real communal variance correspond to them), moreover, iterations tend to push them towards more negativity.

Comment: In the above example, would it be inappropriate to say factor 1 explains 94% of the common variance? If not, how do you interpret that factor 1 and 2 explain 106%?

Comment: I've added a paragraph "Let us look at the final eigenvalues" to [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/102999/3277), that would help you understand the "% of".